# Clarity ClrFormsNextModule *clrIfError Reactive Forms

Tags: vmware-clarity

Using Clarity for a work project and I'm unsure if the new clr-control-error messages work with reactive forms. The example they provide on using multiple error messages is with template forms, but the setup should essentially be the same.

Here is my code:

```
<clr-input-container>
  <label>Password</label>
  <input clrInput type="password" formControlName="password">
  <clr-control-helper>8+ Character Password</clr-control-helper>
  <clr-control-error *clrIfError="'required'">Please Enter Password</clr-control-error>
  <clr-control-error *clrIfError="'minLength'">Password must be 8+ Characters</clr-control-error>
</clr-input-container>

newCompanyForm = new FormGroup({
   email: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
   password: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]),
```

I'm using @clr/angular v0.12.4, angular 6.0.2, and rxjs 6.1.0. I can see the form is still invalid once I begin to type into the input field, but the error message never switches from "Please Enter Password" to "Password must be 8+ Characters". Once the password reaches 8 characters the field is no longer invalid so I'm pretty sure the Validator is working, just the error message is not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `maxLength` and `minLength` are transformed into `maxlength` and `minlength` internally on the errors object. This should fix it below, though I will investigate this and double check it works in both reactive and template-driven forms.

```
<clr-control-error *clrIfError="'minlength'">
```

Comment: Switching the *clrIfError to 'minlength' instead of 'minLength' seems to have fixed the issue. Looks like Clarity will need to update their docs as their example code has it 'minLength' which might have lead to my confusion. Thanks everyone for all your help!

Comment: Thats my fault on the docs, it should reflect the HTML attribute names if they exist (`minlength` is the HTML attribute not `minLength` since HTML is case insensitive anyways).

Answer (score 1):

the [Inputs Documentation](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/input) says

> Note: the validation only displays an error after the user has left
>   focus on an input. This is for better UX where the user doesn't see an
>   error while they are still typing.

This means by design you'll never see error messages while you're typing

Comment: This is intentional to avoid showing an error state when the user is trying hard to fill it in correctly the first time. Its very frustrating to fill in an email and be told the whole time you're typing 'email is invalid' instead of showing the useful helper text.

Comment: Indeed, the documentation says why they made this design, at the end of thip [page](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/forms) they say a real-time validation can be useful in some cases.
Wondering how to do that (BTW documentation is still work in progress)

Comment: I understand that, but even on leaving focus that second error message helper never displays. If I click into the input bar and out I will see the first one always. If I type less than 8 characters and click out the input is still red to signify hat the formControl is still invalid (and the form is still invalid, I cannot submit it), but the the second helper message (minLength) will not display.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz where the problem is reproduced ?? is your code inside a `<form crlForm> .. </form>` ??

Comment: @JeremyWilken here is a stackblitz recreating the problem.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v11-ccu3zj
The minLength error message never gets displayed.

Comment: @MassimoCosta see the stackblitz in other comment

Comment: you need to use `minlength` instead of `minLength` in the template (all lowercase).
@FlashBanistan the template is a mix of clarity v0.11 (ui and icons) and v0.12 (angular). It's better to not mix them

Comment: For the record I've just open a new [Issue](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/2538) in Clarity repository for the documentation issue

Comment: as I wrote in the previous comment I created an Issue in the Clarity repo about that